# Microsoft Graph Explorer Modify Permissions

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I need to enable `Chat.Read` (Allows an app to read 1 on 1 or group chats threads, on behalf of the signed-in user) in the Graph Explorer modify permissions section but I don't see it. I can see other permissions such as `User.Read`.
[image of my modify permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NE5R.png)

I'm really new to this so I don't know how it works. I've tried to make API permission from Microsoft Azure but I still doesn't see `Chat.Read` in the Graph Explorer. I don't know if Azure and Graph explorer is related or I did it the wrong way.

My goal is just to enable `Chat.Read` in my Graph Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this,When you request the corresponding api endpoint, you can find it.
[image]

Or you can find it directly here.

[image]